# Pass variable values to velocity template in Node.js

Tags: node.js, velocity, marko

I have `Velocity` templates stored in a database which contain loops as follows:

```
#foreach($project in $projects)${project.name}#end
```

I want to pass value to project names via a form in Nodejs application, designed in `marko` templating engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a layer of velocity template engine in between